# How to make div FIXED at the bottom when scroll down?

Tags: jquery, css, position, fixed

I've created a fiddle at

**[fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/2UGgc/25/)**

All that I want is make the `DIV#sticker` `FIXED` at the bottom when scroll down until its bottom border (the bottom red border in my example) reaches the bottom of the browser window. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want the text to stick to the page bottom if the red line is not visible (not reached red line with scroll yet), and once you reach the red line the text should stick to that?

Comment: @BeNdErR : I want everytime scrolling down until I see the red line, the DIV#Sticker is not floating anymore but will be fixed when I keep scrolling down), but when I scroll up, it is floating again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to calculate scroll offset + window height, to get the bottom part of the window, and then check if that is greater than element offset + element height. Also, you have to remove bottom margin from the element, if you really want it pinned down to the bottom border.

Code is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("#sticker");
    var pos = s.offset().top+s.height(); //offset that you need is actually the div's top offset + it's height
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop(); //current scroll position of the window
        var windowheight = $(window).height(); //window height
        if (windowpos+windowheight>pos) s.addClass('stick'); //Currently visible part of the window > greater than div offset + div height, add class
        else s.removeClass('stick');
    });
});
```

I have edited your html a bit, so you can see it properly (added more scroll), but you can see the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/2UGgc/33/ or full-screen version at http://jsfiddle.net/2UGgc/33/show/